# Permission denied when trying to run script as other user

Tags: bash, debian, permissions, su

I'm trying to run a script as another user that starts a piece of software (Etherpad), which is run like so (from root):  `su -c "/var/www/etherpad-lite/bin/run.sh" -s /bin/bash etherpad` but I'm getting the following error: `bash: /var/www/etherpad-lite/bin/run.sh: Permission denied`

This had previously worked perfectly, and only stopped working after I installed a bunch of things for another project I'm working on, none of which should have affected etherpad.

/var/log/auth.log shows this:

```
Aug 12 19:59:21 bhs1 su[7289]: Successful su for etherpad by root
Aug 12 19:59:21 bhs1 su[7289]: + /dev/pts/1 root:etherpad
Aug 12 19:59:21 bhs1 su[7289]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user etherpad by root(uid=0)
Aug 12 19:59:21 bhs1 su[7289]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user etherpad
```

I've done some searching and I found a couple of things that could cause this, but none are relevant to my problem:

- The file is chmodded to 777 (`-rwxrwxrwx`) and it's owned by the etherpad user. I only changed it to 777 to make sure it wasn't a permissions issue, it was something like 700 before.
- The file system doesn't have noexec enabled

I'm running Debian 7.6 on a dedicated server.

Comment: Do you have `SELinux` enabled? It might as well be a problem.

Comment: @Ramesh I found some SELinux related files on the server (`/selinux` and `/etc/selinux` exist) but, following a guide to disable it (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/how-to-disable-selinux-redhat-fedora-debian-unix/), none of the specified config files exist on my server

Comment: I'm not saying that it is wrong, and I don't have a Linux server to test this on right now, but I've never seen the user specified at the end of an su command. Does anything change if the command becomes `su etherpad -c "/var/www/etherpad-lite/bin/run.sh" -s /bin/bash`? (It may be perfectly acceptable to have it at the end, but a quick internet search did not show any examples of that).

Comment: What happens if you `su etherpad` and do an `ls /var/www/etherpad-lite/bin/run.sh`?  Or `ls` the individual components?  Rule out an actual permissions problem first and that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have run.sh with "read by all" privilegs, but if e.g. /var/www/ is with privilegs "read only by root" you will get "permission denied" error message.

check permissions of all directories in the path

```
/var/
/var/www/
/var/www/etherpad-lite/
/var/www/etherpad-lite/bin/
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Something had indeed changed /var/www so that it was no longer executable. Thank you very much :)